# Keycloak Theme Selector Provider - Create not called

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-services

I would like to extend the functionality of a Theme Selector Provider in Keycloak. To do so I have extended the `ThemeSelectorProvider`, `ThemeSelectorProviderFactory` and `ThemeSelectorSpi`.

**CustomThemeSelectorProvider**

```
import org.keycloak.models.KeycloakSession;
import org.keycloak.theme.Theme;
import org.keycloak.theme.ThemeSelectorProvider;

public class CustomThemeSelectorProvider implements ThemeSelectorProvider {

    public final static String ID = "theme-selector";

    private final KeycloakSession session;

    public CustomThemeSelectorProvider(KeycloakSession session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

    @Override
    public String getThemeName(Theme.Type type) {
        return "base";
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {}
}
```

**CustomThemeSelectorProviderFactory**

```
import org.keycloak.Config;
import org.keycloak.models.KeycloakSession;
import org.keycloak.models.KeycloakSessionFactory;
import org.keycloak.theme.ThemeSelectorProvider;
import org.keycloak.theme.ThemeSelectorProviderFactory;

public class CustomThemeSelectorProviderFactory implements ThemeSelectorProviderFactory {

    @Override
    public ThemeSelectorProvider create(KeycloakSession session) {
        System.out.println("This isn't called");
        return new CustomThemeSelectorProvider(session);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(Config.Scope config) {
        System.out.println("This is called");
    }

    @Override
    public void postInit(KeycloakSessionFactory factory) {
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
    }

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return CustomThemeSelectorProvider.ID;
    }
}
```

**CustomThemeSelectorSpi**

```
import org.keycloak.provider.Provider;
import org.keycloak.provider.ProviderFactory;
import org.keycloak.theme.ThemeSelectorSpi;

public class CustomThemeSelectorSpi extends ThemeSelectorSpi {

    @Override
    public boolean isInternal() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "customThemeSelector";
    }

    @Override
    public Class<? extends Provider> getProviderClass() {
        System.out.println("Not called");
        return CustomThemeSelectorProvider.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<? extends ProviderFactory> getProviderFactoryClass() {
        System.out.println("Not called");
        return CustomThemeSelectorProviderFactory.class;
    }
}
```

**jboss-deployment-structure.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi" />
            <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private" />
            <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-services" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I've also created an `org.keycloak.theme.ThemeSelectorProviderFactory` and `org.keycloak.theme.ThemeSelectorSpi` file in the `META-INF/services` directory in the resources.

When I run `Keycloak` it runs the `init` method of the provider but not the `create` method and nothing else appears to happen. My other `EventListenerSpi` works fine but I cannot get the `ThemeSelectorSpi` working.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to use the same ID as the default provider factory (`DefaultThemeSelectorProvider`).

**CustomThemeSelectorProviderFactory**

```
@Override public String getId() {
    return "default";
}
```

Also instead of implementing the interfaces I extended the `DefaultThemeSelectorProvider` and `DefaultThemeSelectorProviderFactory` as I want to use the existing functionality. In theory this shouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to configure the provider in `standalone.xml`
(see https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/how-to-change-theme-selector-provider/7894)
or via the cli

```
bin/kc.[sh|bat] --spi-theme-selector-my-theme-selector-enabled=true --spi-theme-selector-my-theme-selector-theme=my-theme
```

(https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#implementing-an-spi)

Comment: Do I need to use either of these methods? I've been looking at this https://github.com/aerogear/keycloak-metrics-spi repo and I just need to copy the jar into the `providers` directory and it will instantiate the provider correctly. I don't need to add a standalone.xml or arguments to the cli.

Comment: are you running quarkus version?

Comment: Yes, 18.0.2. Also I've tried copying the code exactly as in the documents you sent and added the arguments but it still doesn't register it.

Comment: sorry, did not work with quarkus. but sounds like it discovered your factory but did not use it, maybe it is still using a default one :\

Comment: Yes that sounds likely as it is running the `init` method but not the `create` methods. I'll keep looking thank you.

Comment: this works on my keycloak v19.0.1 `bin/kc.[sh|bat] build --spi-theme-selector-provider=myEmailThemeSelector`